# [keras]Many to many probability prediction using LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

My problem is to predict the error probability of a time series data.
In the data, we have (n_samples, timesteps, features), where timesteps are the maximum length of the time series. The training y_train has one_hot labels of each time point being an error or not.

X_train and y_train are padded with zeros, so a masking layer is added.

In order to predict the error probability, I have an implementation as below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value = 0, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 
X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(para['hiddenStateSize'], 
return_sequences = True)))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Activation('softmax')))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam')
print(model.summary())

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = epochs, batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = False)
```

The question is: The first data points in the samples are always over-predicted. Is there a better implementation of the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by over-predicted?

Comment: LSTM's do take a few steps to start understanding how the sequence works. You could maybe use longer sequences and discard the edges? (Since you're using `Bidirectional`, this is probably happening on the other end too - beware of the masking) .

Comment: @MarcinMożejko, by over-predicted I mean the predicted probability of error is higher than it should be. This dataset is imbalanced though, with 99% of the data point being correct (not error).

Comment: Can you test your data in order to check if a probability of having an error in a first step is significantly higher than in other steps? Maybe your network is learning a proper pattern?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko, thanks for your comments. The error actually got accumulated overtime, which means the first several time points should have less error than the latter ones.

Comment: Has that solved your problem?

Comment: @DanielMöller, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experimented much with bidirectional lstms for time-series prediction but here are 2 things that I would change in your model:

I would either use `categorical_crossentropy` with `Dense(2)` and `softmax`:

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Activation('softmax')))
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam')
```

Or `binary_crossentropy` with `Dense(1)` and `sigmoid`:

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Activation('sigmoid')))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam')
```

Also try the `dropout` (or `recurrent_dropout`) parameter of the LSTM

```
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, dropout=0.2, return_sequences = True)))
```

Comment: thanks@Julio. Any reason why categorical_crossentropy works on one_hot but binary_crossentropy works on label?

Comment: For the formulation and difference let me refer you to [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9302/the-cross-entropy-error-function-in-neural-networks) but basically both are log likelihood estimators, let's say categorical crossentropy is the general case that expects more than one output but binary crossentropy expects just one, and that output needs to be either 0 or 1.